# Где строке выделяется память?

Tags: c++, строки, память, строковый-литерал

Есть например такая запись:

```
const char* s = "Hello, World!";
```

Как это можно понимать?Мы присваиваем указателю адрес на первый символ строки?Но где у нас эта строка хранится когда мы ее пишем так в присваивании?Я понимаю,когда у нас существует объект string и на него указывает указатель.И почему без const нельзя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, *приблизительно* так...

Компилятор встречает `"Hello, World!"`. Размещает массив из 14 символов **где-то** в памяти, причем эта память может быть даже памятью только для чтения (потому и нужен `const` - менять литерал вы не имеете права. Вы же не пытаетесь менять, скажем, двойку в выражении `int i = j*2;`? Так уж принято...).

А потом сохраняет адрес первого символа в переменной `s`. И теперь мы можем узнать, где именно в памяти расположена эта строка.

Так понятнее?

Comment: А если мы просто напишем литерал без присваиваний всяких,как оператор: "Hello, World!"; то что произойдет? выделится память и сразу удалится?

Comment: Думаю, что оптимизатор выбросит его вообще.

Comment: По поводу константности. Если в программе встречаются несколько одинаковых строковых литералов, то в памяти может быть сохранён только один экземпляр, а во все места, где он используется будет просто подставлен адрес этого единого экземпляра. И если бы литерал не был константным, то его изменение в одном месте программы повлияло бы на все места программы, где он встречается. Но это не точно))) Поправьте меня, если Я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @EOF Не уверен, но, кажется, он так может, если ему *разрешить*...